# Facebook iPhone web app Authentication not working

Tags: iphone, facebook, web-applications, mobile, oauth

i have made a web app for the iPhone that connects to facebook using oAuth.

When i try this on my computer everything works fine: i can click login on my page, it redirects to a authentication page of Facebook, i click OK, redirects back to my page and i'm logged in.

When i do the same thing on my iPhone: i tap login on my site, it redirects to the facebook auth page. But THEN it changes to a mobile page and that page is just blanc. There is nothing on it and the 'title' is "UNTITLED"...

How can i fix this ? (or is this a bug at Facebook ?)

Thanks

Evert

Answer (score 0):

In the Facebook Developer page for your app, have you enabled "Native iOS App" checkmark
and the fields in that section.

Like you have to specify the bundle id of your app, you have to enable Facebook login radio button  and also you have to enter the url scheme of your app in the Url Scheme suffix field.
Standard is to prefix fb to your fb app id and use it as the url scheme.

Also make sure you enter this urlscheme in the Xcode project in the info.plist file
under URL types . This will be used to redirect to your app once the authentication is successful/failed.

Comment: Thank you, but i have a problem: it's not a native app, it's a web app. (written is html/js/php...) That means that i DONT HAVE a bundle id or whatever else in XCode... So how can i solve this ?

Comment: There is a section for web app as well in the facebook app settings.            "Website with Facebook Login". Did you check that. You ned to enter your site url there